# Eliminate trailing whitespace from HTML Email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am coding an HTML email template that provides our users with a temporary password to sign into their account. However, I'm trying to get rid of the trailing whitespace that is normally added to HTML email elements, so that if the user selects the line they can just copy the password with no extra characters.

I tried using a div element to wrap the password, as this gets rid of the whitespace, but still if the user clicks and drags to select (as opposed to double clicking), an extra space is still selected, like so:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
...
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <div>myTempPassword</div>
    </td>
</tr>
....
```

To reproduce this problem, make sure instead of double clicking on the div, you click before the beginning of the line and drag the mouse all the way to the right. Now not only the div with the text gets selected, but also some extra space after it.

The second solution I tried was to turn the password text into an invisible input field, so when the user tries to select it, only the text inside of that input field is selected. I also made it readonly to make sure users wouldn't try typing unto it. This worked beautifully at first, except on some email clients like Android Mail, the password area shows a blinking cursor, as the client software tries to treat it like an input field.

Here is the code for that:

```
...
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <input readonly="readonly" class="pw-input" style="width: 270px; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px; color: #EA1675; border: none;"
                                                                    type="text" value="myTempPassword" />
    </td>
</tr>
....
```

To patch that issue, I tried setting the cursor property using CSS, but most mobile email clients don't support that property.

Does anyone have other suggestions for me to either:

1) Get rid of the blinking cursor in my input field without using the cursor CSS property...

or

2) Use another method to remove the trailing whitespace from the password when the user clicks and drags to select?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the password generated? Is the generator adding space?

Comment: are you sure that your template engine is not adding the space character?

Comment: @Syfer When I hardcode the password I am still having the same issue. So it-s not the generator.

Comment: @FlorianGrell Same as above. When I check the html on my local browser without going through the templating engine, I still get the problem.

Comment: @FlorianGrell On second thought, it might be the email client causing the issue. My HTML locally actually looks fine, but the whitespace problem happens when I sent it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Typical issue with inline level elements, that white space is actually a normal space between the element in the markup and the browser doesn't remove it, because it's exactly like the space you put between words it has to stay.

Try to select both the below text, and see the effect

```html
<div>
  mytempPassword
</div>
<div>mytempPassword</div>
```

Comment: You're right. I've eliminated the Fiddle, as it wasn't helping me reproduce my problem. I've put the password the way you're saying but email clients are still rendering it with whitespace, even though the html doesn't....

Comment: Well, how's the passwords are generated ? also can you provide a snippet of the html with the corresponding CSS

Answer (score 0):

The trailing whitespace appears for some users and not for others depending on their browser and or os. For example, I copied your HTML and didn't get the trailing whitespace. Because of this I wouldn't recommend accounting for it because it might look a bit weird for people who don't get it in the first place.

However, if you want to try to fix it, you can use this JavaScript which will make the width of the element smaller to account for it.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('pw-input')[0];
element.style.width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('width'))-10;
```

If you would like you could then set the overflow-x property to visible so the text appears the same, or you could set it to scroll because the user will be copying the text anyway so it doesn't matter if they can read it all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The use of Javascript however is extremely discouraged for HTML emails, as most clients won't be able to run it.

Comment: JavaScript don't work on emails. The work around will have to be without JS.

Comment: Instead you could try using CSS to set the width to `calc(X% - 10px)` instead of `X%`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a much simpler way than I thought. Code is below:

```
<tr style="font-size:0;">
    <td style="font-size:0;" align="center">
        <div style="font-size:0;"><a style="font-size: 30px; text-decoration:none;">{{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}</a></div> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i wouldn't recommend that it doesn't work on some browsers [Read This](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with same situation sending temp pwd's to users, and adding br line break fixed trailing space:

```html
<p>
    <strong>User Name:</strong> ^^param_uid^^<br>
    <strong>Temporary Password:</strong> ^^param_pwd^^<br>
</p>
```

hth, cheers ....